# Is there some way to tell PHP to use proper-precision floats/decimals WITH the standard/natural syntax?

Tags: php, floating-point, decimal, precision, floating-accuracy

I find it very annoying and cumbersome to have to remember to use, and then actually use, the various `bc*` functions instead of `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, etc., whenever money or anything important is involved.

If you don't understand what I'm talking about, PHP basically uses "inaccurate" `float`s for its built-in, natural syntax, which apparently most other programming languages also do, for speed purposes. PHP "fixes" this by providing functions that you must use instead to get accurate decimal numbers.

But it's so ugly to have nested function calls:

```
$leftovers = bcsub($account_balance, $total_cost_for_products);
```

instead of just a clean:

```
$leftovers = $account_balance - $total_cost_for_products;
```

Is there really no way to do something like this?

```
php_ini('full_accuracy_decimals_mode', true);
$leftovers = $account_balance - $total_cost_for_products;
[...]
php_ini('full_accuracy_decimals_mode', false);
```

?

Comment: So you basically want to reprogram what the built-in operators do, is that right?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, temporarily.

Comment: OK. Fair question,  but AFAIK that's not possible in php. Other languages such as c# do have mechanisms where you can define what some of the operators do for specific types, but I don't believe php does. Perhaps someone will correct me.

Comment: I am wondering what `php_ini()` is. Normally, you would use [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set).

Comment: @MarkusZeller It's me forgetting what `ini_set()` was called...

Comment: This has come up [several](https://externals.io/message/108300) [times](https://externals.io/message/115648) with a lot of people interested to various degrees, and also some great discussions, but to date nothing has been done about it yet.

Comment: You should absolutely not use floats _at all_ for dealing with currency. Use an integer of the base unit of the currency, eg: $1 == 100 cents. There are a number of libraries out there that use this method to track currency accurately, as well as implementing methods to divide 3 monies among 2 people and handle the remainder without simply losing it. Eg: https://github.com/moneyphp/money

Comment: Also, for the purpose of argument, floating point numbers are equally as "accurate" as the decimals you write out. Where decimals can only accurately represent composite fractions of base 10, floats can only accurately represent composite fractions of base 2. Try to represent something like 1/3 in _either_ and you've introduced inaccuracy. Fractional values in _any_ base only become "accurate" when you convert them to integers with an implied decimal and use special logic for edge cases, eg: money libraries.